# Does $\lVert\mathbf{x}^{(n)}-\mathbf{x}^{(n-1)}\rVert_2\rightarrow0$ imply convergence of $\mathbf{x}^{(n)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

A sequence $\{\mathbf{x}^{(n)},n=1,2,...\}$. If $\lVert\mathbf{x}^{(n)}-\mathbf{x}^{(n-1)}\rVert_2\rightarrow0$, does it also imply the convergence of the whole sequence $\{\mathbf{x}^{(n)}\}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please try to state things more clearly on your question. For instance, where is your sequence defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Take for example

$$x^{(n)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$

But a similar result is that every Cauchy's sequence in a complete metric space converges.